# Redirecting to HTTPS for a static React app hosted in Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-app-engine, https

I have a nodejs app hosted in GAE flexible environment. We've setup the google-managed SSL and the https route works.

But since we're serving the application statically we can't force the redirect from the server side(to my knowledge)

Here's the server code(I call the start method from index.js):

```
const express = require('express')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

/**
 * Basic web server construction.
 * Parameter function passed into 'start' as serverProcess
 *    contains the actual meat of the server side processing
 *    for the node.js backend
 */
class WebServer {
  constructor () {
    this.app = express()
    this.app.use(express.static('dist/public'))
  }
  /**
   * Begins a web server executing the 'serverProcess' function provided
   * bodyParser.json() used as middleware to enable POST requests with JSON body content
   * @param {Function} serverProcess The business logic function for the node.js backend as a whole
   */
  start () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        this.server = this.app.listen(PORT, function () {
          console.log('Web server being created')
          resolve()
        })
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        reject(e)
      }
    })
  }
  stop () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        this.server.close(() => {
          resolve()
        })
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message)
        reject(e)
      }
    })
  }
}

module.exports = WebServer
```

What can I do make sure that it always redirects to https?

I've heard of x-forwarded-proto but I'm not sure what that is and how to implement it, and since it's a flexible environment I can't use the handlers that GAE provides.

Answer (score 1):

So the way I figured out how to solve this was to use a package called express-https-redirect, which was a express middleware that I simply had to setup using express.use('/', httpsRedirect())

Also I took out the routes their own component class and set them up in the index.js file.

This is what my index.js file looks like now (used to be web.server.js was started from index.js)

```
'use strict'
require('dotenv').config()
const consts = require('./consts/consts')
const httpsRedirect = require('express-https-redirect')

console.log(consts.database)

const express = require('express')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

const app = express()

app.use('/', httpsRedirect())
app.use(express.static('dist/public'))

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Web server was started at ', PORT)
})
```